# Mysql Database connection denied

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-ec2

I am trying to get my Symfony 3 app running in production mode on an Amazon EC2 instance.

I am have the code in the correct place, and then I try to setup any dependencies with composer by running

```
export SYMFONY_ENV=prod
composer install --no-dev --optimize-autoloader
```

but get the error

```
> Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::installAssets

[Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\ConnectionException]
An exception occured in driverL SQLSTATE[HY000] [1044] Access denied for user 'my-user'@'127.0.0.1' to database 'my_database'
```

This error is then passed down to `[Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException]` and `[PDOException]` before the script terminates.
This is then followed by the message

```
[RuntimeException]
An error occured when executing the "'assets:install --symlink --rela'\''web'\'''" command:
```

which is then followed by the same errors as at the beginning.

My parameters.yml file is

```
parameters:
    database_host: 127.0.0.1
    database_port: 3306
    database_name: my_database
    database_user: my-user
    database_password: mypassword
    server_version: 5.6
    mailer_transport: smtp
    mailer_host: 127.0.0.1
    mailer_user: null
    mailer_password: null
    secret: Mysecret
    registration_permitted: true
    registration_limit: 3
```

and the user `my-user` has all permissions on the database `my_database` except GRANT.

I have been trying to solve this for a few hours to no avail, other solutions I came across involved misspelt usernames/passwords/databases (triple-checked) or needed the server version adding (which hasn't made a difference).

**Additional Info**

- Running `mysql -u my-user -p` prompts for the password and then allows me to log in.
- Running `mysql -u my-user -p -D my_database` prompts for the password and then returns `ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user 'my-user'@'localhost' to database 'my_database'`.
- Logging into mysql as root and running `SHOW GRANTS FOR 'my-user';` returns `ERROR 1141 (42000): There is no such grant defined for user 'my-user' on host '%'`.
- Logging into mysql as root and running `SHOW GRANTS FOR 'my-user'@'localhost';` returns `GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'my-user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD hashedPassword`.

**Additional Info 2**
After deleting `my-user` (`'my-user'@'localhost'` and `'my-user'@'127.0.0.1'`) and then recreating them using `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON my_database.* TO 'my-user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';` and also `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON my_database.* TO 'my-user'@'127.0.0.1' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';` and then `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;` The output of `SHOW GRANTS FOR 'my-user'@'localhost'` is then

```
GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'my-user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD 'passwordHash'
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON 'my_database' TO 'my-user'@'localhost'
```

and similar output for `'my-user'@'127.0.0.1'`.

But this is still giving me the same errors as before, any more ideas?

Comment: What happens if you ssh to the server and run `mysql -u my-user -pmy_database my_database`? Also can you run in mysql `SHOW GRANTS FOR my-user`?

Comment: Thanks @Moein - I've added the output of those commands to the end of the question (too long for a comment) and it looks like that user does not have the permissions I thought they did. Do you know why this might be? Looking at the tables through phpmyadmin shows the permissions as being there.

Comment: GRANT USAGE ON is basically no grant :D 
Try running `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'my-user'@'localhost'` and then `FLUSH PRIVILEGES`

Comment: Haha, that explains it, thanks (will run it when I get home). What would be the correct command to grant just a subset of privelleges (select, insert, update, delete, alter) to only a specific database? That was what I originally tried to do but evidently did it wrong.

Comment: The reason for wanting to restrict the privileges and access only to a specific database for that user was because that is the user my application uses (so it shouldn't have access to the entire set of databases).

Comment: @Moein Should be `ON my_database.*` for security reasons :)

Comment: @Moein - I have tried your suggestion but still get the same errors (commands run and ouput added to the question), any further ideas?

Comment: @Kvothe I'm confused you didn't run what I suggested you to run
`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON my_database.* TO 'my-user'@'localhost'`

Comment: @Moein That is what I ran. It's working now though, it turned out that after the command you suggested I also needed to change the `database_host` in my `parameters.yml` to `localhost` instead of `127.0.0.1` (not certain why, but it worked). Do you want to add your suggestions as an answer and then I can accept it? Thanks for your help :)

Comment: That would be nice
I also explained the reason why you had to change your param ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in comments you did not have any privilege on the database.
So running this fixes your problem:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON my_database.* TO 'my-user'@'localhost'
```

About your doubt why you had to change it to localhost in your params because that's what you're telling mysql
Imagine you want to restrict database access to only a specific ip in your network you could run

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON my_database.* TO 'my-user'@'192.168.1.10'
```

So replace 192.168.1.10 with 127.0.0.1 and you can use 127.0.0.1 in your parameters